# Trying to add multiple sequentially number columns to data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I need to add 7 empty columns (to represent days of the week) to an existing data frame and especially helpfull if they can be preceeded by the word "Day"

I have previously used 7 lines like this

`DF$'Day 1' <- ''`

`DF$'Day 2' <- ''`

Is it possible to shorten this, possibly using a loop?

eg. `for(i in 1:7) {DF@'Day [i]' <- ''}`

Which obviously doesn't work otherwise I wouldn't need to be asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you attempt to assign to non-existent columns then they just get created for you automagically.

```
DF <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 'hi')
days <- paste0('Day',1:7)
DF[,days] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create an empty data frame then you can do the following:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=20))
names(DF) <- paste("Val", 1:20, sep="")
```